# Transparent view background turns black

Tags: ios, swift, background, transparency, alpha-transparency

I want to make the view of a view controller semi-transparent. For that I have set the background color like this in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
```

When the view controller is presented, the background appears as I need it and then it turns black right away.

[image]

Why is this happening?

This is the code for showing the `PopupViewController`:

```
@IBAction func didTapShowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PopupViewController())
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I uploaded a demo project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iri6nzmuts9afc3/NibViewDemo.zip?dl=0) as well.

Comment: This may be a great opportunity to create a custom presentation which may give you a number of design ideas that you had not thought of before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may add the flag `overCurrentContext` (or `custom`), so your `present`  might be something like:

```
@IBAction func didTapShowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: PopupViewController())
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Swift 4

Comment: thanks, works like a charm! I used this instead of isModalInPresentation = true for IOS 13, cause my background was turning black